# Are google Reviews consider to be proof against owners of business?

Tags: germany

I Want to be honest international students are treated very badly in Germany, I was learning in educational institutions and I was treated badly **very rude** staff and doesn't answer emails if you want to share opinions and truth online you will get threats from these institutions and such. and if you want to talk to them they will only **talk with you alone** so they can deny any statement later on. I thought I was the only one until many many other international students from different places said the same.
So in an attempt to collect proof against my place I archived and screenshot many negative reviews  before they are forced to be deleted, and all of them have replies from these institutions which is proof this review and statements were made by real students in my college
for example, the most common thing these students complain about is why they never got their deposit back and how the director is taking advantage of them

**so are these online reviews consider a proof of any kind?**

Comment: Please clarify your question (add intention - what would you do with the info you seek?).

Comment: will in short many educational institutions try their best to not leave any evidence against themselves like emails which will be used against them if they lied, so I had some problem with them, and most evidence I have are verified reviews from students calling them out on their BS, so I can Sue them if they tried to start BS with me

Comment: what type of BS? like double the prices, being rude, racist, ignoring students emails for weeks, threats to go to courts over the dumbest reasons, faking positive reviews, being like Karens and threatening students to call the police on them just to scare them if they don't want to talk

Comment: @JustLookingforadvice Being rude may mean something different where you are from, than it means in Germany.

Answer (score 4):

Any google review would be hearsay. That means, it would be proof that someone posted a review, and what was written in the review, but it wouldn't be proof that any facts claimed in the review were true.

As it is proof of posting, anyone who feels slandered could sue for slander and be successful (depending on circumstances). But trying to claim that the contents of a review is a true fact will fail. You can of course try to contact the person writing a review, and they might be willing to appear in court as a witness. That would make it a statement by a witness which would be taken seriously, and not just hearsay. Since lying in a court as a witness is a serious matter, someone posting a false review will very likely not be willing to appear in court for you.

Comment: what about fake positive reviews? many websites offer businesses to buy fake positive reviews for very cheap? is this illegal in Germany? (btw i have evidence they use fake reviews)